# Statically calling error while updated php version

Tags: php

I have a web application that I just updated from 5.3 to 5.5 on my server and i get around 200-300 errors like below. I understand this is a deprecation error and is it possible to solve all in one go and not hide the errors?

```
Strict standards: Non-static method xyz() should not be called statically.
```

Comment: It's very easy to solve this. You're missing the `static` keyword from certain functions. So you have `function`(for example) and calling it statically. It needs to be `public/protected/private static function`.

Comment: but it appears in 200 files. i am not sure where do i correct it

Comment: You'll have to do 'em by hand. I can't really think of any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Function `xys` is not static, but is clled statically. See difference below.

```
<?php

// Calling non-static function, first create object by class
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->xyz();

// Calling static function (you are doing this)
Foo::xyz();

?>
```

You should define your function like this. Find where `xyz` is defined.

```
public static function xyz(){}
```

Then it wont throw strict standard error. Just add `static` to your function and **all** errors will be gone.

You don't have to change it in all 200 files. This function is just called in 200 files. That dosen't meen that you have bug in all of them.

**NOTE:** from docs

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

So, if your are using `$this` in function `xyz`, you have to use my first example. Then it means fixing all 200 files.

See docs for [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function static.
The fix is a simple one , but it has to done in all places where you called a static method that way. I think there is no other way.